# my PHP insert to DB function does not work

Tags: php, android, web-services

i created an Android client app and a PHP Webservice , i just send some user info to webservice to login or register, my client is fine and yet no error to connect and call webservice and parameters on the client also is ok, my login function (select function) on the server also is fine with no error; **but** the insertion function on the php webservice doesnot work, please help me , what should i do ? every time i call register function, i receive "database error".
here is my insert function in the webservice :

```
// RPC method 1 (register)
function reguser($email, $password, $tell, $fp, $long, $lat, $ckey) {
    $id=22;
    $vercode = createRandom();
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    if(!$db){
        return 'Error: cannot open the connection to DB';
        exit;
    }
    // insert new user in DB
    mysql_select_db('user_info');
    $query = "insert into personal(id, email, password, tell, fp, long, lat, vercode, ckey) values ('".$id."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$tell."', '".$fp."', '".$long."', '".$lat."', '".$vercode."', '".$ckey."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
     if($result){
         return 'ok'; 

     } 

        else {
            return 'Database error';
        }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: refer this  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use qoutes for column name in query.

```
insert into personal(`id`, `email`, `password`, `tell`, `fp`, `long`, `lat`, `vercode`, `ckey`)
```

Comment: Those are not quotes but backticks :) It's good practise but not mandatory